# Rotating two seprate objects(paths) in Canvas

Tags: android, canvas, rotation

I have two arrows drawn on my canvas using the canvas.DrawPath(). I'm using canvas.rotate() to rotate, but it is obviously rotating both arrows by the same amount.

Id like to be able to rotate one arrow one way, and rotate the other arrow in a different direction.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `canvas.rotate()` you are altering the transformation matrix associated to the canvas, so all what you paint after that will be affected by the current state of the matrix, you have to do the following:

```
canvas.save();     //Save current canvas matrix state
canvas.rotate(angle);
canvas.DrawPath(); //Draw first arrow
canvas.restore();  //Restore canvas matrix to saved state
canvas.DrawPath(); //Draw second arrow without the rotation
```